# Is there a way to clear chat history in Webchat which uses DirectlineJS and not React

Tags: botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

As per the below github issues link for Chatbot and BotFramework.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1846

We can clear chat history by assigning a new instance to store variable, which triggers a  DIRECT_LINE/DISCONNECT action. Now this works in React Webchat. But, I have tried in Web-chat Java script version and the issue seems to still persist, i.e., when the store variable is replaced the previous chats are not removed.

Any confirmation from the community will be relieving as there are many open issues in Botframework github that its confusing. I'm sharing a few that I found out.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1293
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/issues/124

If No, can this be achieved in some other way? any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it. So, just replacing the variable will not work. You need to render the store variable to update/replace it in webchat.js code.

```
await window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
        store: widgetStore
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

Comment: But, rendering both store and directline together give render error.

Answer (score 0):

The [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo provides a sample that demonstrates precisely how to do this. The sample is [04.api/h.clear-after-idle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/h.clear-after-idle). The readme also includes some caveats to be aware of.